# Combine Buy/Restore in app purchase button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, mkstorekit

in our app I have a purchase button & a restore button however I would like to make it so that instead of 2 seperate buttons I can just use one, which then prompts what to do.

Would anyone be able to assist in editing the code below so that when the user clicks the button, a UIAlert pops up with one button to say Upgrade, one to say Restore, the other Cancel.

Here is the current code used to buy / restore;

```
-(IBAction) actionRemoveAds
{
    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeatureA];
}

-(IBAction) actionRestore
{
    [MKStoreManager sharedManager];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

}


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag==111) {


        if (buttonIndex==0) {

            [[MKStoreManager sharedManager]buyFeatureA];

        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks,
Chris

Comment: Why would you want to do this? When a user chooses to Restore purchases, you will get a receipt for every purchase made. How do you expect to handle cases of multiple purchases of multiple items? Please stick with the recommended and accepted UI rather than create something awkward and non-standard, your users will thank you.

Comment: Hi Rick, i'll leave it, no problem, I thought I was being untidy by not combining the button, by have 2 separate buttons.

My idea was to call a UIAlertview when the upgrade button was pressed, and in that UIAlert would be an option to upgrade, restore or cancel.
I will stick to separate buttons, I am guessing that is the recommended Apple guideline.

Comment: I can see what you were going for, but in this case, providing a separate button specifically for the restoration of previous purchases is recommended, and what users are familiar with. Good Luck with your project!

Comment: No problem at all, thanks Ric :)